# How to redirect if template missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I created a mobile mime type for my Rails app (ie. two types of view files, `html.erb` and `mobile.erb`).

I have some static pages (eg. `static_pages/about.html.erb`) that have not been converted to `.mobile` format.

How can I automatically redirect to the root_path if someone tries to access a missing template on their mobile?

Comment: That sounds really, really annoying for your users.

Comment: You should rescue the exception and handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though this is annoying, I can understand you are working in the process.

There is the rough idea, though not verified

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate, :with => :template_not_found

  private

  def template_not_found
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

#### add for further question

For your further question, it seems you are serving normal site and mobile site from same domain, and use User Agent or other JS method to detect.

I think a better practice here is to have normal pages at service at first(if normal site is your first focus), then adapt to mobile later.

So, if a template missing, visitor can always get normal page served either by render or redirect even he's using  mobile.

You are not the only one who links to your pages. A user may add social bookmark, Google will index the site. These all cause your links exposed.

If most of them are covered, I think add a rescue for missing template is okay.

Comment: that's perfect, thanks Billy. 

Is it bad practice to have pages that don't exist in a second format? My mobile pages only link to pages that exist in mobile. Therefore, the only way for someone to get to a missing template is if they manually enter an address (e.g. `myaddress.com/about`) for which a template doesn't exist. Would you still define this as a below standard user experience?

Comment: @umezo, my pleasure the answer helps. Please check my update for the later question.